# ¿Para sirve la función is_feed en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Indagando en la documentación de wordpress, encontré algo así:

```
if ( is_feed() )
    $title;
```

Pero no termino de comprender su funcionalidad y para qué utilizarlo.  Alguien me podría apoyar, por favor.

Saludos.

Comment: Como bien dice @Patrick, es un método de [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_feed/), que sirve para determinar si el argumento o array de argumentos que le pasas es una publicación del tipo `feed`. Este método devuelve un booleano `true` o `false` como resultado de la comprobación.

Answer (score 0):

La función `is_feed()` devuelve un booleano (`true` o `false`) si la query que está activa en este momento es del feed. Es decir, de la página de entradas de tu blog.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed

https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-feeds/

Comment: No es del todo correcto. La página de entradas de tu blog no es un feed. Con feed se refiere a RSS o Atom por ejemplo. Entonces `is_feed()` devuelve verdadero si la query se trata de un feed de esos, pero devolverá falso si es  la página de entradas de tu blog.